# How to display image on local file system with Image?

Tags: react-native, image

The display for image from local file system stops work with `Image` in React Native 0.66. Here is the code:

```
<Image 
    source={{uri: img_source}}
.../>
```

Here `img_source` is a string returned by image picker (not from react-native-cameraroll). here is an example of `imp_source` in iOS emulator:

```
/Users/macair/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/107E832C-4828-47D9-83D1-DABE20BA32F3/data/Containers/Data/Application/5C0BB55D-4834-47A9-B7CF-22CE9355C3FD/tmp/react-native-image-crop-picker/A52D733E-DB54-4C72-90DE-2444C3C45FD4.jpg
```

The app has the permission to pick up image from local gallery. Tried `'file://' + imp_source` with no avail. How to make the code above working with `Image`?

Answer (score 0):

Use the uri value from image picker. It looks like you're attaching a bunch of things prior to the root of the application in your URL. Without seeing the code, I'm assuming the URI should be file:///tmp/react-native-image-crop-picker/A52D733E-DB54-4C72-90DE-2444C3C45FD4.jpg, not the full system path.